# Compress achart engine - husk specify chart types

Tags: android, compression, achartengine

Is it able to compress the achart engine?

I don't want to use all of chart types, just one or two, so including a whole library 100KB jar file isn't good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) on your application it will remove classes that are not referenced in the code, including classes in library JARs assuming it is properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you don't start hacking the AChartEngine jar file. It is indeed nicely decoupled, but there are pieces depending one on each other and if you start removing stuff you will end up with a version that doesn't work.

As it was mentioned above, 100+ KB is not that big.